# Read different languages with IMAP in Ruby

Tags: ruby, email, encoding, imap, chinese-locale

I am acquiring a list of folders from an email account, some of these have chinese characters.
However the output from Ruby, is not proper. How do I get it display the correct characters?

Example:

```
"Group: &gC9UCE6SUtVQs2StgKFO,WcJllBRbFP4-"
```

The group of obscure characters is actually a list of chinese characters.

I have tried switching the encoding to utf-8. However that results in the same thing.

I have even used the `force_encoding` method on the string, yet same result.

Comment: This is 'modified UTF-7 encoding', used for IMAP folders.  Look to see if your IMAP library has a decoding function for folder names.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Net::IMAP.decode_utf7](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/IMAP/decode_utf7/class):

```
Net::IMAP.decode_utf7('&gC9UCE6SUtVQs2StgKFO,WcJllBRbFP4-')
=> "耯合互動傳播股份有限公司"
```